# Kubernetes authentication issues pulling ECR images

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

[Kubernetes docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#using-aws-ec2-container-registry) say using AWS ECR is supported, but it’s not working for me. My nodes have an EC2 instance role associated with all the correct permissions but `kubectl run debug1 -i --tty --restart=Never --image=672129611065.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/debug:v2` results in `failed to "StartContainer" for "debug1" with ErrImagePull: "Authentication is required."`

**Details**

The instances all have a role associated and that role has this policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
            "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
            "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
            "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
            "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
            "ecr:ListImages",
            "ecr:BatchGetImage"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }]
}
```

And the kubelet logs look like:

```
Apr 18 19:02:12 ip-10-0-170-46 kubelet[948]: I0418 19:02:12.004611     948 provider.go:91] Refreshing cache for provider: *credentialprovider.defaultDockerConfigProvider
Apr 18 19:02:12 ip-10-0-170-46 kubelet[948]: E0418 19:02:12.112142     948 pod_workers.go:138] Error syncing pod b21c2ba6-0593-11e6-9ec1-065c82331f7b, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "debug1" with ErrImagePull: "Authentication is required."
Apr 18 19:02:27 ip-10-0-170-46 kubelet[948]: E0418 19:02:27.006329     948 pod_workers.go:138] Error syncing pod b21c2ba6-0593-11e6-9ec1-065c82331f7b, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "debug1" with ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image \"672129611065.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/debug:v2\""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if you change permissions on an InstanceProfile they take effect immediately. However, there must be some kind of setup phase for the Kubelet that requires the permissions to already be set. I completely bounced my CloudFormation stack so that the booted with the new permissions active and that did the trick. I can now use ECR images without issue.

Answer (score 2):

From those logs, I suspect one of three things:

- You haven't passed the `--cloud-provider=aws` arg on the kubelet.
- The correct IAM permissions weren't in place when your kubelet started up. If this is the case, a simple bounce of the kubelet daemon should work for you.
- You're on a k8s version < 1.2. Although, this one seems unlikely, given the date of your question.

Comment: Yes, it was kind-of the cloud-provider flag. I'd added the flag and then also added permissions to ECR to the role I'd assigned to the nodes but it wasn't working. As noted in my answer below I also had to bounce the CloudFormation stack as the Kubelet would not reconfigure itself even after restarting it with the new permissions. It must have been saving state somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think you also need the image pull secret configured for ecr images. You can reffer the below links for details.

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_GetStarted.html

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/499

1) Retrieve the docker login command that you can use to authenticate your Docker client to your registry:

aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1

2) Run the docker login command that was returned in the previous step.

3) Docker login secret saved /root/.dockercfg

4)Encode docker config file

```
    echo $(cat /root/.dockercfg) | base64 -w 0
```

5)Copy and paste result to secret YAML based on the old format:

```
    apiVersion:  v1
    kind: Secret
    metadata:
      name: aws-key
      type: kubernetes.io/dockercfg
    data:
      .dockercfg: <YOUR_BASE64_JSON_HERE>
```

6) Use this aws-key secret to access the image

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
      name: foo
      namespace: awesomeapps
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: foo
          image: janedoe/awesomeapp:v1
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: aws-key
```

Comment: The problem is that ECR credentials only work for 12 hours so this solution would only work until the credentials expire.